# Clear jQuery validation on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a simple form. When I click 'submit' I validate the controls using the jQuery validation methods. I'm having trouble clearing the validation when clicking a 'cancel'.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Custom method
$.validator.addMethod("valueNotEquals", function (value, element, arg) {
    return arg != value;
}, "This field is required.");

var jqueryValidator;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>").click(function () {   

        jqueryValidator = $('#masterForm').validate({
            rules: {
                <%=gddTank.UniqueID %>: {
                    valueNotEquals: "-1"
                },
                <%=gddCanister.UniqueID %>: {
                    valueNotEquals: "-1"
                },
                <%=gddCane.UniqueID %>: {
                    valueNotEquals: "-1"
                },
                <%=gddStraw.UniqueID %>: {
                    valueNotEquals: "-1"
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function (element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            }
        });

    });

    $("#<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").click(function () {   

        jqueryValidator.resetForm();

    });

});

</script>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Wilky.

Comment: Consider using `console.debug()` with `Firebug` or `browser console`. It will make your job of finding the problem much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").click(function () {   
        jqueryValidator.resetForm(); 
        $('#masterForm').get(0).reset();
});
```

You would think that the `resetForm` method would take care of this all for you, but for some reason you have to take the extra step of calling `reset` on the form itself.

Comment: @Wilky - I've made an example form, seems to work well (and in a cancel button, don't even need to call `form.reset()`:  http://jsfiddle.net/nxXNz/29/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#<%= btnCancel.ClientID %>").click(function () {   
    jqueryValidator.resetForm();
    $(jqueryValidator.currentForm).find('input:not([type="button"],[type="submit"]),textarea').val('');
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this defeats the purpose of the plugin's `resetForm()` method.